# Phonegap App what should be the Best Way

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am Creating an app which will store data of songs in database,

i wil be fetching them with JSON from server

but calling JSON remotely is making my app slower so

i thought to use sqllite but songs will get upadated dailly

i will have to fetch them too

but storing all tracks in sql lite will be also not the ideal option so

can you please suggest me best way to sort out this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a revision number on the device and in your remote DB.

Then do something along these lines:

- On app launch, poll your DB server: `GET http://myapp.com/get_json_update?rev=41`

  - where `rev` is the revision number of the DB on the client.
- On the server:

  - Compare the rev # with the one sent by the client.
  - If `local rev == remote rev` return an empty JSON object.
  - If `local rev > remote rev`, do a `diff`, JSONify the objects that have been added since the last rev, return to client.
  - If `local rev < remote rev`, something went terribly, terribly wrong.
- On the client

  - Push the new objects into your DB.
  - Update the DB rev #.

Comment: but i cant store all tracks in local db cause all are not gonna be used

Comment: You don't have to store the *actual* tracks in the local DB. Have a "meta" DB of all songs *available* (updated as outlined above) and a separate one for the songs actually *downloaded*.

Comment: yeah i m not gonna store actual mp3 wil just store its path bt still dont you think i dont hv to store path of all tracks it wil be arround million

Comment: Uhmm … What would be the alternative? Transmitting a million tracks via AJAX/JSON every time?

Comment: No Thats Godamn slower but hope some one in here can find better answer

Comment: The best approach to your problem, performance-wise – at least judging from the data you provided – is the one I described: Keep track of revisions (minimal computing required), do delta updates (minimal amount of data transmitted between server and client), keep a cache/copy on the client (no repeated transmission of data).